# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: News is not mapped [from News where status =: active]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, mysql-workbench

I connected Spring 5.0.19.RELEASE and Hibernate 5.2.10.Final.

I'm getting an error: **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: News is not mapped [from News where status =: active]**.

The same error is also obtained with other requests (for example "from News").

The work of the application reaches the DAO layer and executes a query from the database.
When I trying to get information from BD and display this list in the web app.
I'm a newbie in Java.

I tried the options below:

- [why-org-hibernate-hql-internal-ast-querysyntaxexception-customer-is-not-mapped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52189276/why-org-hibernate-hql-internal-ast-querysyntaxexception-customer-is-not-mapped)
- [Hibernate error - QuerySyntaxException: users is not mapped [from
  users]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954590/hibernate-error-querysyntaxexception-users-is-not-mapped-from-users)

but it doesn't work.

I hope to get help in my confused situation.

***My DataBase in MySQL***

```
  CREATE TABLE `news` (
  `idnews` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `brief` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `content` varchar(5000) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idnews`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
```

***Error:***

```
Jun 22, 2021 9:10:23 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/spring-myproject] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: News is not mapped [from News where status =: active]] with root cause
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: News is not mapped
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:171)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:324)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3696)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3585)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:720)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:576)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:313)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:261)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:266)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:546)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:655)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:679)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:102)
    at myproject.dao.impl.SQLNewsDAO.all(SQLNewsDAO.java:28)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:197)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:295)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy26.all(Unknown Source)
    at myproject.service.impl.NewsServiceImpl.takeAll(NewsServiceImpl.java:28)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:197)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:295)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy27.takeAll(Unknown Source)
    at myproject.command.GoToMainIndexPage.execute(GoToMainIndexPage.java:27)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:799)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:981)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:873)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:888)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
```

***Entity:***

```
package myproject.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="news")
public class News implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5421029433949953632L;
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="idnews")
    private int idnews;
    
    @Column(name="title")
    private String title;
    
    @Column(name="brief")
    private String brief;
    
    @Column(name="content")
    private String content;
    
    @Column(name="date")
    private LocalDateTime date;
    
    @Column(name="status")
    private String status;

    public News() {
    }
    
    public News(int idnews, String title, String brief) {
        super();
        this.setIdnews(idnews);
        this.title = title;
        this.setBrief(brief);
    }

    public News(int idnews, String title, String brief, String content, LocalDateTime date) {
        super();
        this.setIdnews(idnews);
        this.title = title;
        this.setBrief(brief);
        this.setContent(content);
        this.setDate(date);
    }

    public int getIdnews() {
        return idnews;
    }
    public void setIdnews(int idnews) {
        this.idnews = idnews;
    }
    
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getBrief() {
        return brief;
    }
    public void setBrief(String brief) {
        this.brief = brief;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
    
    public String getDate() {
        DateTimeFormatter newFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
        String formattedDateTime = date.format(newFormat);
        return formattedDateTime;
    }
    public void setDate(LocalDateTime date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((brief == null) ? 0 : brief.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((content == null) ? 0 : content.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((date == null) ? 0 : date.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + idnews;
        result = prime * result + ((status == null) ? 0 : status.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((title == null) ? 0 : title.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;

        News other = (News) obj;
        if (brief == null) {
            if (other.brief != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!brief.equals(other.brief))
            return false;
        if (content == null) {
            if (other.content != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!content.equals(other.content))
            return false;
        if (date == null) {
            if (other.date != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!date.equals(other.date))
            return false;
        if (idnews != other.idnews)
            return false;
        if (status == null) {
            if (other.status != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!status.equals(other.status))
            return false;
        if (title == null) {
            if (other.title != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!title.equals(other.title))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "id: " + this.idnews + "\n" +
                "title:" + this.title + "\n" +
                "brief:" + this.brief + "\n" +
                "content: " + this.content + "\n" +
                "date: " + this.date + "\n" +
                "status: " + this.status;
    }

}
```

***Controller layer***

```
package myproject.command;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import myproject.entity.News;
import myproject.service.NewsService;
import myproject.service.ServiceException;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/mainIndexPage")
public class GoToMainIndexPage {
    
    @Autowired
    private NewsService newsService;
    
    @RequestMapping("/showMainPage")
    public String execute(Model theModel) throws ServletException, IOException, ServiceException {

        List<News> news = newsService.takeAll();
        
        theModel.addAttribute("news", news);
        
        return "main_index_page";
    }
}
```

***Service layer***

```
package myproject.service.impl;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import myproject.dao.DAOException;
import myproject.dao.NewsDAO;
import myproject.entity.News;
import myproject.service.NewsService;
import myproject.service.ServiceException;

@Service
public class NewsServiceImpl implements NewsService {

    @Autowired
    private NewsDAO newsDAO;

    //@Override
    @Transactional
    public List<News> takeAll() throws ServiceException {
        System.out.println(1);
        List<News> news;
        
        try {
            news = newsDAO.all();
        } catch (DAOException e) {
            throw new ServiceException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return news;
    }

}
```

***DAO layer***

```
package myproject.dao.impl;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import myproject.dao.DAOException;
import myproject.dao.NewsDAO;
import myproject.entity.News;

@Repository
public class SQLNewsDAO implements NewsDAO {

    // need to inject the session factory
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<News> all() throws DAOException {
        System.out.println(2);
        Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query<News> theQuery = currentSession.createQuery("from News where status =: active", News.class); /*"from News where status = 'active'"*/
        List<News> news = theQuery.getResultList();
        return news;
    }
}
```

***ApplicationContext***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">        

    <!-- Step 3: Add support for component scanning -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="myproject" />

    <!-- Step 4: Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Step 5: Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Step 6 Add support for reading web resources: css, images, js, etc 
        ... -->
    <mvc:resources location="/resources/"
        mapping="/resources/**" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"
        id="messageSource">
        <property value="resources/messages" name="basenames" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Step 7 Define Database DataSource / connection pool -->
    <bean id="myDataSource"
        class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl"
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/news_management_spring_hibernate?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&amp;useSSL=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC" />
        <property name="user" value="111" />
        <property name="password" value="111" />

        <!-- these are connection pool properties for C3P0 -->
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="30000" />   
    </bean> 

    <!-- Step 8 Setup Hibernate session factory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="src.main.java.myproject.entity" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Step 9 Setup Hibernate transaction manager -->
    <bean id="myTransactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />             
    </bean>
    
    <!-- Step 10 Enable configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTransactionManager" />
</beans>
```

***pom.xml***

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>by.htp.spring.main</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-myproject</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-myproject Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <!-- Generic properties -->
        <maven.compiler.release>1.8</maven.compiler.release>
        <!-- Web -->
        <jsp.version>2.2</jsp.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <servlet.version>3.1.0</servlet.version>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <spring-framework.version>5.0.19.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- BD -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>8.0.23</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Dependency Spring Framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-taglibs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Other -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mindrot</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbcrypt</artifactId>
            <version>0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- New depend -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.26.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>spring-myproject</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                    <server>tomcat-server</server>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

***main_index_page.jsp (view)***

```
        <!--News-->
        <div class="list_news">
            <c:forEach var="AllNewsFromBD" items="${news}"> <!--requestScope.-->            
                <div class="list_news_block">
                    <div class="">
                        <h5 class="title_news">
                            <c:out value="${AllNewsFromBD.title}" />
                        </h5>
                        <p class="">
                            <c:out value="${AllNewsFromBD.brief}" />
                        </p>
                        <c:if test="${sessionScope.auth == true}">
                            <div class="">
                                <a href="Controller?command=go_to_one_news_page&idnews=<c:out value="${AllNewsFromBD.idnews}"/>">
                                <c:out value="${ReadMore}" /></a>
                            </div>
                        </c:if>
                        <br/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </c:forEach>
        </div>
```

There are lot of posts on stackoverflow in which addressing the same issue. But I was unable to find a definite solution for this.

Please help

Comment: That is a lot of material, but not being an expert, I couldnt say what to leave out for a [mcve]. But kudos for carefully formatting and writing up your content!

Comment: why you use "from News where status =: active" (colon) ?

Comment: Your `packagesToScan` property is wrong. It must not include `src.main.java`

Comment: When I delete “src.main.java.”, I ‘m getting an exception:  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]

Answer (score -1):

You could try this:

```
Query<News> theQuery = currentSession.createQuery("select news from News news where news.status = :active", News.class); 
            theQuery.setParameter("status", active);
     return theQuery.getResultList();
```

Comment: The issue isn't the query.